# sql sumar y restar en una misma columna

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

tengo el siguiente problema en sql y no se como resolverlo.. Necesito sacar el saldo total y no conozco las herramientas, se sumarlo o restarlo bajo la condicion de que "operacion" sea deposito o extraccion, pero no se como hacer todo junto para que vaya sumando o restando!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento pero claro... me falta poder restarle las extracciones!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor. saludos.

Comment: Ahi esta, ya lo subi!

Comment: Gracias @Kevin, recuerda agregar como texto el código o los scripts pero es importante agregar siempre más información, por lo pronto ya tienes una buena respuesta de Patricio Moracho , saludos!

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente por publicar código y datos como imagen, no como texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21).

Comment: uh no lo sabia, gracias por avisarmelo!

Comment: @Kevin, no solo te lo _avisaba_, la idea es que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/445793/edit) y cambies las imágenes por texto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que buscas se conoce como "suma condicional", es decir sumar de cierta forma según una condición, en este caso lo que hacemos es "negativizar" los montos que no son depósitos. La estructura de la condición es `CASE WHEN <condición> THEN <valor si> ELSE <valor No> END`

```
SELECT sum(monto * case when operacion = 'deposito' then 1 else -1 END) as 'Monto total' 
       from ejemplo
```

Comment: ohh mil gracias, veia cosas similares pero no explicaban nada, y no lo entendia! es sencillo pero bueno, el uso del "case when" no lo tengo y bueno, me sirvio mucho. Gracias!

Comment: @KevinCánepa recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio!