# Restar totales en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

Tengo una tabla donde los campos son:

```
ID
FECHA
TITULO
TIPO
CUENTAS
IMPORTE
```

Para registrar movimientos de dinero. En tipo tengo `Ingreso` y `Egreso`. Lo que quiero saber es como sacar el total de cada cuenta restando su ingreso-egreso.

Es decir que yo tendría que sumar los importe de tal cuenta (Por ejemplo "Banco X") pero solamente filtrando Ingreso y Egreso. Una vez que tengo los dos resultados tendría que restarlos para que me de el neto de la cuenta.

Lo mismo me gustaría hacer con el total de todas las cuentas, es decir restar todos los ingresos menos todos los egresos para tener el resultado neto.

Comment: En las etiquetas por favor limita a lo que si estés usando sea MySQL o Access

Answer (score 4):

Vamos por pasos

1. para determinar la cantidad a sumar, debes valerte de valor almacenado en `Tipo`, si es `Ingreso` es positivo y si es `Egreso` es negativo. Esto lo podemos lograr multiplicando el valor almacenado en `Importe` por (+1 o -1) según el caso. El +1 y -1 lo podemos obtener con una sentencia `case`, cuya sintaxis sería el equivalente a `case when Tipo = 'Ingreso' then 1 else -1 end`. Estoy asumiendo que si no es `Ingreso` necesariamente es `Egreso`.
2. Luego, para sacar el neto por cuenta, agrupamos por el campo `CUENTAS` y sumamos el valor obtenido en el paso anterior

En SQL, luciría algo como:

```
select   cuentas
       , sum(IMPORTE * case ... end) as neto /* la sentencia case que ya he explicado */
  from MiTabla
 group by cuentas
```

Para sacar el resultado de todas las cuentas, simplemente obtenemos la suma, ya sin agrupar por cuentas, lo cual nos *resume* toda la tabla en una sola fila de resultados.

```
select sum(IMPORTE * case ... end) as neto /* la sentencia case que ya he explicado */
  from MiTabla
```

OJO, que estoy asumiendo que almacenas siempre un valor positivo en `IMPORTE`. Una solución que simplifica aún más las cosas, es almacenar un valor positivo cuando son ingresos y un valor negativo cuando son egresos, entonces simplemente tienes que sumar el valor de la columna importe, así:

```
select   cuentas
       , sum(IMPORTE) as neto
  from MiTabla
 group by cuentas
```

Finalmente, he escrito la respuesta usando SQL estándar, dado que actualmente muestras más de un motor en las etiquetas, espero que corra en ambos motores y no voy a probarlo en ninguno...

Comment: Patricio moracho contesto exactamente lo mismo hace 2 horas... estaba por cerrar esta pregunta como duplicada hasta que vi tu respuesta...

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/445793/324

Comment: Ahora la vi y creo que esta es un poco más amplia que la otra pregunta, aunque efectivamente son muy similares. No tengo nada en contra del cierre, ni de la respuesta de Patricio, pero si fuese por la amplitud de la respuesta, me quedaría con esta, y si fuese por la pregunta, solo porque la otra tiene el código y los datos como imagen, también. Para no tomar partido, no votaré. Si vos consideras que debe cerrarse esta, adelante, no tengo inconveniente. :)

Comment: Salomonicamente iba a usar el tiempo como factor de cierre. No copias esta respuesta para alla y las cerramos por duplicadas?

Comment: Ya la respuesta de Patricio tiene +4, creo que la mía no tendría cabida ya en ese caso. No quisiera estar en tus zapatos, ya que no puedes simplemente votar como un simple mortal y dejar que la comunidad decida. :D

Comment: las dos respuestas son buenas.. las dos preguntas tienen problemas.. en fin.. dejemos todo como esta entonces... capaz hasta tenemos suerte y alguno acepta la respuesta

Comment: Ese sería un buen argumento para cerrar la otra, veamos que pasa. :) Un saludo!

Comment: @jachguate ya se aceptó la otra pregunta, ¿será que ya cerramos esta?

Comment: @Eduardo, por mi parte adelante, ejerce tu voto para el cierre. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Todo lo puedes hacer dentro de la misma query, como no diste más datos de tu schema, te dejo la sintaxis general :)

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(IMPORTE) FROM Table1 where Conditions) - (SELECT SUM(IMPORTE) FROM Table1 where AnotherConditions) AS neto;
```

Como verás se hace una query con dos queries adentro.

SELECT (query 1) - (query 2) AS neto;

La primera query debería ser de los ingresos y la segunda de los egresos.

Para hacer la suma de los totales de la columna importe se usa el `SELECT SUM(IMPORTE)` y para limitarlo a lo que quieres se junta con las condiciones que necesites usar.